# Is there an efficiency hit for a constant formula in a C #define?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was perusing some kernel source code from `cpufreq_governor.h` and saw this:

```
/*
 * The polling frequency depends on the capability of the processor. Default
 * polling frequency is 1000 times the transition latency of the processor. The
 * governor will work on any processor with transition latency <= 10ms, using
 * appropriate sampling rate.
 *
 * For CPUs with transition latency > 10ms (mostly drivers with CPUFREQ_ETERNAL)
 * this governor will not work. All times here are in us (micro seconds).
 */
#define MIN_SAMPLING_RATE_RATIO         (2)
#define LATENCY_MULTIPLIER          (1000)
#define MIN_LATENCY_MULTIPLIER          (20)
#define TRANSITION_LATENCY_LIMIT        (10 * 1000 * 1000)
```

Would it not be more efficient to change the last line to read:

```
#define TRANSITION_LATENCY_LIMIT        (10000000) /* (10 * 1000 * 1000) */
```

Comment: For readability alone, it is better to leave it as is.  ( Just my opinion. ), My eyes see and understand `10 * 1000 * 1000` faster than `10000000`.

Comment: For the record, the relevant part of standard is this: http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.6.html Note that it says "can be", not "must be" evaluated in "translation" (i.e. compile) time.

Comment: Another thing to note here that a compiler **must** be able to calculate 10 * 1000 * 1000 at compile time *elsewhere* (integer constant expressions), so that it *didn't* do so in this context would be just plain silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would it not be more efficient to change the last line to read:
>
> ```
> #define TRANSITION_LATENCY_LIMIT        (10000000) /* (10 * 1000 * 1000) */
> ```

Most probably it wouldn't make any difference.

Any half-decent compiler should be able to calculate `10 * 1000 * 1000` at compilation time.

Comment: Good point. I spend all day in BASH and get my coding habits there. *Software won't let me accept your answer for 8 minutes*

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself:

how many zeros are there in your suggestion (or alternative, what is the number)

`#define TRANSITION_LATENCY_LIMIT        (10000000)`

Tiring task. This is a lot more intuitive and easy (and easy to maintain):

`#define TRANSITION_LATENCY_LIMIT        (10 * 1000 * 1000)`

Also, `(10 * 1000 * 1000)` is more convenient way to represent 10 microseconds (10 times 1 millionth (1000 * 1000) of a second)

Also, no efficiency matter here as it will be computed by compiler.

Comment: it should be noted that one millionth of a second is a **microsecond**, not a millisecond.  one millisecond is one thousandth of a second.

Comment: @Tau fixed it, thanks

Answer (score -1):

No doubt you change it and get more efficient code because multiplication is take more CPU cycle comparison to addition and subtraction but you loss code readability of your source code. but don't wary today's compiler is so smart and done it you for compile time and this process is know as code optimization.

Comment: _more efficient code because multiplication is take more CPU cycle_.  Not likely true.  the computation will occur at compile-time.

Comment: definitely computation will occur at compile-time. i mean if it's not done at compile time and executed this operation (10 * 1000 * 1000) at run time then code take much time compare to this (10000000) because multiplication take more CPU cycles.

Comment: Susheel, Just a note when leaving comments, If you want to get someone's attention, (that you left a comment addressed to them) start with their moniker prepended with the `@` symbol.  ( eg. @ryyker - _comment_)  For comments  under the owners answer or post, the `@` symbol is not necessary.  They will be automatically notified that a comment has been left for them.  Regarding your response, Its an arguable point, as seen in some of the other comments and answers.  ( note, I did _not_ down-vote :) )